# How to fix "Blob size exceeds INT_MAX" error in Caffe?

Tags: caffe

While training `1200x1200px` images in Caffe, I faced the following error:

```
check failed :shape[i]<=2147483647/count-(18361800vs.4294967)Blob
 size exceeds INT_MAX
```

How can I circumvent this issue ?

Comment: Could you give a bit more details? How exactly does your blob size look like?

Comment: There are lots of ways to reduce a blob size.  For example, reduce the batch size (cutting batch size in half cuts your largest blob in half).  Increasing strides (in pooling layers or convolution layers) will reduce the blob size (output) from that layer, etc...